# Invalid manifest message by launching

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, launching-application, manifest.json

By launching my extension I get this message:

> Invalid manifest

My manifest file is loaded. Here is it:

```
    {
      "name": "GoogleMapToContact",
      "short_name": "GoogleMTC",
      "description": "Save Google Geopoints to Google Contact",
      "manifest_version": 2,
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "start_url": "/?homescreen=1",
      "background_color": "#000000",
      "theme_color": "#0f4a73",
      "icons": {
        "src": "map.png",
        "sizes": "256x256",
        "type": "image/png"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect tags in your manifest.json. First 4 lines are OK.
Bad tags, that are not allowed in extensions manifest, are:

- **start_url** (do you want to specify you entry point?)
- **background_color** (it should be done in your popup file)
- **theme_color**

Icons are written in slightly wrong way :) Here is suggested file

```
{
    "name": "GoogleMapToContact",
    "short_name": "GoogleMTC",
    "description": "Save Google Geopoints to Google Contact",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "map.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "icons": {
        "16": "map16x16.png"
    }
}
```